# Set default screen resolution in Lubuntu

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, xrandr

I'm running Lubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and got a really annoying problem. I can set the screen resolution using rxandr or axrandr but every time I restart the computer it changes back.

The computer is used as a HTPC. It sets the default resolution to 4K but I want to use

FullHD = `1920x1080`

The computer consists of the following components:

- KINGSTON SSDNOW V300 60GB SSD 7MM SATA/600 MLC
- KINGSTON 4GB 1600MHZ DDR3 CL9 DIMM HYPERX BLU
- INTEL CORE I3 4330 3.5GHZ 4MB S-1150
- GIGABYTE GA-H87N-WIFI H87 S-1150 MINI-ITX

How can I set the default resolution in Lubuntu?

Comment: Normally Lubuntu sets the highest possible resolution automatically. What resolution do you get automatically, and what resolution do you want? Please post the output of `xrandr`. And please describe your computer. The more details, the better. Otherwise we can only give general advice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my original post with more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would modify the resolution with

```
xrandr -s 1920x1080
```

There is a file (maybe empty) or you can create the file

```
~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

You can add the `xrandr` command line into that file,

for example with the editor nano (text mode) or leafpad (GUI).

and reboot.

---

*Edit June 2022:* Newer Lubuntu versions (for example 22.04 LTS) contain the directory

```
"$HOME"/.config/autostart
```

where you are supposed to put a desktop file. This is a similar structure for autostart as in standard Ubuntu Desktop.